# Parsing a mix of plaintext and <b>, <br> tags into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, html, cheerio

The [wiki pages](https://moonbreaker.fandom.com/wiki/Zax_Ja%27kar) that I am trying to parse include the following html:

```
<div
  class="pi-smart-data-value pi-data-value pi-font pi-item-spacing pi-border-color"
  style="width: calc(1 / 1 * 100%)"
  data-source="unique_ability"
>
  <b>Captain</b><br /><b>"Back off!"</b><br />Push target on hit.
</div>
```

What I would like to parse the content of the div into is an array like this:
`["Captain", "Back off!", "Push target on hit."]`

If I use the [text()](https://cheerio.js.org/interfaces/CheerioAPI.html#text) method from cheerio (`const uniqueAbilities = $('[data-source="unique_ability"]').text()`) I get a long string like this: `Captain"Back off!"Push target on hit.` If I use the [html()](https://cheerio.js.org/interfaces/CheerioAPI.html#html) method (`const uniqueAbilities = $('[data-source="unique_ability"]').html();`) from cheerio I get the HTML content of the node, but I am then unable to parse it as a string.

How would you parse this html into the desired output?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to obtain your desired output but it might not cover all the other cases :

```js
//get HTML content
let data = $('[data-source="unique_ability"]').html();
console.log(data);
//remove all carriage return
data = data.replaceAll(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
console.log(data);
//split the string  around HTML tags
data = data.split(/<[^>]+>/g);
console.log(data);
//remove empty strings from the array
data = data.filter(el => el.trim() != "");
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div
  class="pi-smart-data-value pi-data-value pi-font pi-item-spacing pi-border-color"
  style="width: calc(1 / 1 * 100%)"
  data-source="unique_ability"
>
  <b>Captain</b><br /><b>"Back off!"</b><br />Push target on hit.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end, I did not end up using this exact solution, but the regex and `replaceAll` functions that you used got me close enough to the final version, so I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to jQuery and that "cheerio" thingy, if your runtime supports treeWalker/[NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator), you can do something like:

```js
const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
    document.querySelector('[data-source="unique_ability"]'),
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
);
const result = [];
while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
  const trimmed = currentNode.nodeValue.trim();
    if(trimmed) {
        result.push(trimmed);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div
  class="pi-smart-data-value pi-data-value pi-font pi-item-spacing pi-border-color"
  style="width: calc(1 / 1 * 100%)"
  data-source="unique_ability"
>
  <b>Captain</b><br /><b>"Back off!"</b><br />Push target on hit.
</div>
```